# Display Image on JSP (Image as SOAP Attachment)

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, soap

I am calling a **SOAP webservice** which returns me an **Image as SOAP Attachment** i.e.

```
<Image>
   <xop:Include href="cid:10ee9.." >
</Image>
```

I will get this image in attachment i.e.

```
AttachmentPart attachment = (AttachmentPart)iterator.next();
```

1. **Need to know that How can i pass this attachment to JSP to be displayed**?
2. **Also Need to Store it in Database so BLOB type is fine for that?**

Is attachment need to be **converted** or will be stored in **DB as it is**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service response may contain a picture as base64 or as an attachment outside the envelope. Example decoding base64:

```
public static BufferedImage decodeToImage(String imageString) {

    BufferedImage image = null;
    byte[] imageByte;
    try {
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
        image = ImageIO.read(bis);
        bis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}
```

JAVA already have an API for processing SOAP with attachments.

```
SOAPMessage response = connection.call(requestMessage, serviceURL);
Iterator attachmentsIterator = response.getAttachments();
while (attachmentsIterator.hasNext()) {
    AttachmentPart attachment = (AttachmentPart) attachmentsIterator.next();
    //do something with attachment 
}
```

As long as your images are stored on a folder that can be served by your server, you just need to add elements to your JSP pages and have their 'src' attribute hold the path to your image.

For instance, let's say you're storing your images in a folder named 'images' that can be served by your server. You'll have to insert a element in your JSP page such as:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/images/image_name.jpg" /img>
```

Comment: Actually i am done till getting attachment part.
images will not be saved on secondary storage. After calling the webserivce i need to display image directly on JSP and then also storing it in DB for future use.
I am asking in which format the attachment can be taken to the JSP?

Comment: You can store them in a BLOB column.

Comment: Alright about the Storage in DB..
i am done till 
AttachmentPart attachment = (AttachmentPart) attachmentsIterator.next();
Can you help like how can i take this "attachmnet" to the jsp to display the image?

Comment: Do i need to covert this "attachment" to a byte Array? or some other format?
Or can it be directly passed to JSP?

Comment: I need to display the image on JSP before saving it into DB

Comment: You need to just do opposite way in the given example here we are creating attachment from binary data now you should create binary data  from AttachmentPart http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/xml/javax_xml_soap_attachmentpart_getrawcontent.htm

Comment: That Tutorial is quite relevant and gave me the idea what to do next :)
Many Thanks @constantlearner

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do this

You can do like this

```
try{
         String fileName = request.getParameter("image");             
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("d:\\"+fileName));
         BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);             
         response.setContentType(contentType);
         BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
         for (int data; (data = bis.read()) > -1;) {
           output.write(data);
         }             
      }
      catch(IOException e){

      }finally{
          // close the streams
      }
```

For passing the image path you can use src like this

```
<img src="<%=request.getParameter("image")%>">
```

Comment: Images will not be stored on Secondary storage. Otherwise it would be nothing difficult.